# using gluLookAt and mouse to channge viewing angle in opengl/glut

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Hello so i am attempting to use a mouse function to move the perspective of gluLookAt to no luck so far i have attempted to adjust upX and upY based off of the mouse position however I want the program to be able to do an entire 360 rotation around the object based on the mouse movement and would like it to stop when the mouse movement in the window stops. Any help would be appreciated I am still learning

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

float posX=4, posY=6, posZ=5, targetX=0, targetY=0, targetZ=0, upX=0, upY=1, upZ=0;

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0, 4.0/3.0, 1, 40);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluLookAt(posX, posY, posZ, targetX, targetY, targetZ, upX, upY, upZ);  

    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glutWireTeapot(1.5);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
      glColor3f(1, 0, 0); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0); glVertex3f(10, 0, 0);
      glColor3f(0, 1, 0); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0); glVertex3f(0, 10, 0);
      glColor3f(0, 0, 1); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0); glVertex3f(0, 0, 10);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

void usage(){
    std::cout<< "\n\n\
          q,Q: Quit\n\n" ;
          std::cout.flush();
}

void onMouseMove(int x, int y)
{
    posX = x*cos(posY) + PosY*sin(PosX)*sin(yRot) - dz*cos(xRot)*sin(yRot) 
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void KeyboardFunc (unsigned char key, int eyeX, int eyeY)
{
    switch (key)
    {
       case 'q':
       case 'Q':
           exit(0);
           break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void init() 
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    usage();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(300,250);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Final");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(&onMouseMove);
    glutKeyboardFunc(&KeyboardFunc); 
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: please ignore the current onMouseMove code currently attempting random things

Comment: Do you want to move around the scene using lookAt to always keep the scene in the center or rotate the camera? What coödinate transform do want to use to map mouse movement to a sphere?

Comment: im not sure what you mean by what coordinate transform i want to use but the shape is a teapot and i want to be able to move the camera a full 360 around the teapot  based off of the mouse movement in the window

Comment: Actually you should use model matrix to do this job,according to mouse move to change the rotate angle.I think this is the best application.

Comment: Usually one sets the roll to zero, that answer is good advice.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to implement an arcball camera, and you want to do it with the fixed-function pipeline matrix stack, it'd actually be simpler to not use `gluLookAt()` but `glRotate/glTranslate`, like so:

```c
glTranslatef(0f, 0f, -radius);
glRotatef(angX, 1f, 0f, 0f);
glRotatef(angY, 0f, 1f, 0f);
glTranslatef(-targetX, -targetY, -targetZ);
```

where `radius` is the distance of the "camera" to the viewed point, `angX` is the angle around the X axis, `angY` the angle around the Y axis and `(targetX, targetY, targetZ)` is the position of the viewed point (your `targetX/Y/Z`).

You don't have to compute `sin/cos` yourself (it is computed by `glRotatef`) and all you have to do is set/increase `angX` and `angY` in your motion function.

Comment: would this go into the onMouseMove function so that it may be used when the mouse moves or would it be placed elsewhere in the code? thank you for the advise by the way!